# Setting Selection Style BackgroundColor for UITableViewCell Grouped

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to set the background color of a UITableViewCell when it's highlighted in a grouped tableview. The code I'm using now produces this results. Could somebody please inform me of the correct way to do this, so as to maintain the rounded corners of the uitableviewcell?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds] ;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = coolBlue ;
}
```

**Updated Code:**

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = coolBlue;

UIBezierPath *rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.selectedBackgroundView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0f, 8.0f)];

CAShapeLayer *shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

[shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];

cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer.mask = shape;
rounded = nil;
shape = nil;
```

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By Using Bazier Path you can able to give top two or bottom two or any numbers of corner radius(out of 4 obviously).

Here I am setting top left and top right corner for cell backgroundview:

```
UIBezierPath *rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.selectedBackgroundView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0f, 8.0f)];

CAShapeLayer *shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

[shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];

cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer.mask = shape;
rounded = nil;
shape = nil;  
// you can change the code as per your need
```

And now you just want to set the corner for first and last cell background.

**And Remember to add QuartzCore Framework in your project and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your class.**

you can change the textcolor of textlable when highlighted using:

```
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: your so close! See edited question above. Not sure why topright corner isn't rounding...

Comment: beacause your cell width is large. check your cell size

Comment: your a genius. Thanks for this solution

Comment: My pleasure and not that Genius just a lucky guess :)

Comment: well this solution sure is awesome :) one more thing, how do I keep the text in the UITableviewCell black? Right now it turns to white when the cell is highlighted (i.e. downpressed but not selected)

Comment: are you using custom cell ?

Comment: again Its My pleasure :)

Comment: If you're bored and want to take a crack at another one [+ get more upvotes :)] would you mind looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758164/creating-a-dropshadow-for-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that the cell has clipsToBounds set to YES

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds

Comment: Well another option is to add a radius to your background view cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;

Comment: Last option is to make your own cells http://app-solut.com/blog/2011/04/custom-uitableviewcells-with-round-corners/

Comment: option 2, cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius is almost there, except that it rounds both the bottom two corners for the top cell, and the bottom two corners for the top cell, both of which are unwanted. Do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: In that case you will have to make a custom cell unfortunately but if you follow the tutorial above it shouldn't be much trouble