# Creating a dropshadow for UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-graphics

Would somebody please explain how to create a one or two pixel drop shadow ONLY on the the very last cell (in other words, I don't want a shadow around the entire tableview, just the bottom cell. An image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Use the following code to produce a very nice, subtle shadow to the bottom of your `UITableViewCell`. Makes it look like it's raised slightly out of the page :)

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 49, cell.frame.size.width-26, 3)];/// change size as you need.
        separatorLineView.backgroundColor = shadowColor;// you can also put image here
        UIBezierPath *roundedShadow = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:separatorLineView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0f, 8.0f)];
        CAShapeLayer *newSeparatorShape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
         [newSeparatorShape setPath:roundedShadow.CGPath];

        separatorLineView.layer.mask = newSeparatorShape;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

Also, don't forget to put this at the top of your .m file `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: i am also trying with this bezier path only :)

Comment: @BaZinga yea actually, right now when you select it using the highlight technique you described in your answer to my last question, the shadow is lost, so implementing it with bezier path only might solve that issue...

Answer (score 0):

You could, in tableView:cellForIndexPath: set the cell's background image to one that includes the rounded corners with the shadow.

Comment: Is that really the best way though? Is there no way to do this with the native graphics framework?